# Trying to create an empty set in Clojure

Tags: clojure, set

I have this function called not-elimination which takes an argument and applies the not inference rule which states: (not (not x)) infer x. So for example if my argument is '(not (not a)) then #{a} would be my output. Example 2, Argument: '(not (not (not a))) Output: #{(not a)}

The problem I am running into is the case where my argument is '(not x) which is supposed to return #{} (empty set), but I am getting the error below. Any ideas on what the problem is?

```
    Execution error (IllegalArgumentException) at microproject2.core/not-elimination (core.clj:7).
Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol
```

My code:

```
(ns microproject2.core)

(defn not-elimination [expression]
  (if(not-empty expression)
  (if (= (nth expression 1) "x" )
    (set {})
   (sorted-set-by > (last (last expression))))
  (println "The list is empty")))
```

Comment: `(last (last '(not x)))` is your problem. Also why is `(not (not (not x)))` `(not x)`, but `(not x)` is _not_ `(not x)`?

Comment: I actually found another problem as well. My second if statement never evaluates to true. To answer your question, it returns empty because we cannot infer anything. We can infer '(not x)' because  in (not (not (not x))) the first two nots cancel each other out based on logic rules, so then we are left with not x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that works, including some unit tests:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defn not-elimination
  [expr]
  (if (not-empty? expr)
    (if (= (symbol "x") (second expr))
      #{}   ; and empty set, could use `(hash-set)`
      (sorted-set-by > (last (last expr))))
    :the-list-is-empty))

(dotest
  (is= #{} (hash-set)) ; both are equivalent

  (is= :the-list-is-empty (not-elimination '()))
  (is= (hash-set 'x) (not-elimination '(not (not x))))
  (is= #{ '(not x) } (not-elimination '(not (not (not x)))))
  )
```

It is based on [this template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you!! I now know my mistakes